# How to change column data type in a DataTable that contains data?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datatable

How can I change the data type of data column from an input DataTable (already filled) in VB.NET? Then, I'll put the code in a Blue Prism Code Stage where I have in input:

1. Name of the field (column) that I want to change the data type
2. The data type that I want to convert
3. Input Collection (data table)

Example:

```
Dim InputDT As New DataTable
InputDT.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("test"))
dt.Columns("test").DataType = GetType(Date)
```

Comment: You are going to need to add some example code of what you have already tried before we can help you.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include that?
Take a look at the help section (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), you are much more likely to get a answer if your question is well formatted.

Answer (score 9):

If the DataTable is already filled with data, you **cannot** change the type of any of its columns. If you try to do that, you will receive an `ArgumentException` with a very straightforward message:

> Cannot change DataType of a column once it has data.

A good alternative would be to create a new DataTable (or clone the existing one), change the column type, and then fill it with the data from the old DataTable.

Something like this should work:

```
Dim InputDT As New DataTable
InputDT.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("test"))
InputDT.Rows.Add("1/1/2018")

Dim clonedDT As DataTable = InputDT.Clone()
clonedDT.Columns("test").DataType = GetType(Date)
For Each row As DataRow In InputDT.Rows
    clonedDT.ImportRow(row)
Next
```

Note that in order for this to work, the data in that column *must* be valid for the new type. To handle the case where the existing values cannot be cast to the new type, you can use a `Try.. Catch` statement like the following:

```
' ...
Try
    For Each row As DataRow In InputDT.Rows
        clonedDT.ImportRow(row)
    Next
Catch ex As ArgumentException
    ' An error occurred, use 'ex.Message' to display the error message. Example:
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: How  i handle the exception that can come out when the datatype isn't convertible?

Comment: So what exactly do you expect/want to happen when an existing value can't be casted to the new type?

Comment: I want a massage in BluePrism that warning me that "the old datatype is not convertible in new datatype, plase chose another" but i don't want to mark exception in all row of column that i try to convert

Comment: You can use a [`Try.. Catch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/try-catch-finally-statement) to catch and handle the error. I'm not actually familiar with BluePrism so I hope you know how to display a warning. Anyway, check my edit to know how to get the error message.

Comment: I'm following your instructions to change the data type column, but the new datatable (created with clone() ) doesn't change the data type but keeps the header and records. How can i solve it? I'ts possible that the problem is Clone() ?

Comment: What do you mean doesn't change the datatype? Are you sure you didn't forget to call `clonedDT.Columns("test").DataType = '....`?