# String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated. while inserting records in DB table

Tags: c#, exception, datatable, casting

My user-defined data type is as below

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[CdeSecureList] AS TABLE
(
    [CardRefID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [KEY] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [MIS_Field1] [varchar](60) NULL,
    [MIS_Field2] [varchar](60) NULL,
    [ValidatingCarrier] [varchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [OtherCarriers] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Card Vendor] [varchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [Card] [varchar](266) NOT NULL,
    [Expiration] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Precedence] [int] NULL,
    [AlertEmail] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [maxTktAmt] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [IRP_remark] [bit] NOT NULL
)
```

and in my C# code, I created a datable and made sure the data type matches with my SQL table

```
DataTable dtCloned = dtExcel.Clone();

try
{            
    dtCloned.Columns[0].DataType = typeof(Int32);
    dtCloned.Columns[1].DataType = typeof(string);
    dtCloned.Columns[2].DataType = typeof(string);
    dtCloned.Columns[3].DataType = typeof(string);
    dtCloned.Columns[4].DataType = typeof(string);
    dtCloned.Columns[5].DataType = typeof(Boolean);
    dtCloned.Columns[6].DataType = typeof(string);
    dtCloned.Columns[7].DataType = typeof(string);
    //dtCloned.Columns[8].DataType = typeof(DateTime);
    dtCloned.Columns[9].DataType = typeof(Int32);
    dtCloned.Columns[10].DataType = typeof(string);
    dtCloned.Columns[11].DataType = typeof(decimal);
    dtCloned.Columns[12].DataType = typeof(Boolean);

    foreach (DataRow row in dtExcel.Rows)
    {
        dtCloned.ImportRow(row);
    }
}
```

Yet while inserting the record, I am getting an error

> String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated

I understand this error means

Causes: This error is usually encountered when inserting a record in a table where one of the columns is a VARCHAR or CHAR data type and the length of the value being inserted is longer than the length of the column.

But I made sure the data type is same, so why am I getting the error.

My assumption is row 5 and row 12 in my code is having boolean value (the content is True in both the case), but my SQL data type is bit, is it a problem? How can I fix this?

Comment: Try and set the MaxLength of the varchar columns

Comment: Still getting the same error :(